# Search a text file and print only a part of line to multiple txt files in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file with locations on it.

```
<OverlayObject>
    <PropertyValuePair property="LineControlCategory" value="BDYOR" />
    <PropertyValuePair property="Location" value="|0|LINESTRING (-65.440101 46.999328 0, -65.4018205 46.9315888 0, -65.2459708 46.866914 0, -65.1127481 46.8361129 0)" />
    <PropertyValuePair property="ObjectLabelA" value="13" />
  <OverlayObject>
    <PropertyValuePair property="LineControlCategory" value="BDYOR" />
    <PropertyValuePair property="Location" value="|0|LINESTRING (-65.440101 46.9992462 0, -65.4759729 47.0003057 0, -65.4817235 47.0098503 0, -65.4943889 47.0195827 0)" />
    <PropertyValuePair property="ObjectLabelA" value="9" />
          </OverlayObject>
```

I want my script to search for each line were the location are and write that line to different txt files. so for the text it would by

file1.txt

```
<PropertyValuePair property="Location" value="|0|LINESTRING (-65.440101 46.999328 0, -65.4018205 46.9315888 0, -65.2459708 46.866914 0, -65.1127481 46.8361129 0)" />ode here
```

file2.txt

```
<PropertyValuePair property="Location" value="|0|LINESTRING (-65.440101 46.9992462 0, -65.4759729 47.0003057 0, -65.4817235 47.0098503 0, -65.4943889 47.0195827 0)" />
```

The goal is to have the files like this:

file1.txt

```
    -65.440101,46.999328
 -65.4018205,46.9315888
 -65.2459708,46.866914
 -65.1127481,46.8361129
```

file2.txt

```
    -65.440101,46.9992462
 -65.4759729,47.0003057
 -65.4817235,47.0098503
 -65.4943889,47.0195827
```

So far I have this:

```
with open('OVERLAY.ovl', 'r') as searchfile:
for line in searchfile:
    if "Location" in line:
        print line
```

that gives me only the line with the words "location" in it

and i have this:

```
with open('OVERLAY.ovl', 'r') as input:
for index, line in enumerate(input):
    with open('filename{}.txt'.format(index), 'w') as output:
        if "location" in output:
            output.write(line)
```

this is writing all line to a different txt file.

how do I combine the 2 scripts and even better can anyone help me to my end goal.

Comment: Your XML is not valid, the first `OverlayObject` is not closed. Also, this document does not have a root element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to get the elements you are interested in.

```
from lxml import etree

x = open("your-file.xml").read()
tree = etree.fromstring(x)
for location in tree.xpath('//PropertyValuePair[@property="Location"]/@value'):
    print(location.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].replace(", ", "\n"))
```

Output:

```
-65.440101 46.999328 0
-65.4018205 46.9315888 0
-65.2459708 46.866914 0
-65.1127481 46.8361129 0
-65.440101 46.9992462 0
-65.4759729 47.0003057 0
-65.4817235 47.0098503 0
-65.4943889 47.0195827 0
```

Saving this to files is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: looks great but now i have to install two modules..trying that for the last two hours :) but learning

Comment: What OS are you using? lxml can easily be installed into most Python distributions?

Comment: windows 7. But I got it working now. Script is working great. One thing I was thinking most of my colleges cannot install software on their computers. We use arcgis and have Python27 so I need to make a script without those modules :)

Comment: i am still looking for a code without the use of modules that i have to install. i use python27.

Answer (score 0):

After same study i have the code i want without the use of other modules:

```
f = open('OVERLAY.ovl','r')
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

file.write("X,Y,Feature,FeatureOrder\n")

for line in f.readlines():
    if "Location" in line:
        print(line.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].replace(", ", "\n").replace(" 0", "").replace(" ", ","))
        file.write(line.split("(")[1].split(")")[0].replace(", ", "\n").replace(" 0", ",\n").replace(" ", ","))

f.close()
file.close()
```

I now have this file what i can use in arcgis

X,Y,Feature,FeatureOrder

-64.9734423,46.8886667,

-64.975073,46.9527568,

-65.015054,46.9900623,

-65.0746205,47.0712622,

-65.0990984,47.0740409,